# Indirect Proof with contradiction in premises

Tags: logic

The premises are as follow:

```
1. A
2. A > ~B
3. B
4. C
```

The conclusion is `(A & B) & \~C`

My teacher proceed to use solve it using Indirect Proof.

```
5. ~[(A & B) & ~C ]      AP
6. ~B                    1,2 MP
7. B & ~B                3,6 Conj
8. (A & B) & ~C          5-7 IP
```

If such proof is valid, that means if there are premises with contradiction, I can create any sort of conclusion with IP, even false argument like `A & ~A`. If so, would that make IP not very strict/complete system?

Is there any rule that required AP must be used within the skeleton of IP that result in the reaching the IP conclusion? I think this can prevent creating false argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If such proof is valid, that means if there are premises with contradiction, I can create any sort of conclusion with IP, even false argument like A & ~A. If so, would that make IP not very strict/complete system?

If the premises entail a contradiction, then you can validly derive anything from them.  After all, anything is at least as true as a contradiction.

An Indirect Proof operates as follows: When a contradiction can be derived from an assumption of a negated statement, then we may infer the statement.  This is also known as Reduction to Absurdity (or *Reductio Ad Absurdum* to be fancy).  (Assuming `~P` reduces to an absurdity, therefore `P`.)

```
|  |_ ~P
|  |  :
|  |  B & ~B
|  P
```

Now, the issue you have is that in your teacher's proof, the contradiction is not derived from `~P` *itself*, but from the premises.  This is okay.  In a Natural Deduction indirect proof we do not care about the *origin* of the contradiction, just that it can be *validly derived* within the context of the assumption.  So this is quite valid:

```
|  B           Premise
|_ ~B          Premise
|  |_ ~P       Assumption
|  |  B & ~B   & Introduction
|  P           IP
```

Now, there is a similar rule, Proof Of Negation (or Negation Introduction): When a contradiction can be derived when assuming a position, then we may infer the negation of that position.  This leads to the equally valid inference:

```
|  B           Premise
|_ ~B          Premise
|  |_ P        Assumption
|  |  B & ~B   & Introduction
|  ~P          ~I
```

So `B & ~B` entails not only `P`, but `~P` too!

Well, that just means that a contradiction will entail a contradiction.  Meh.  There's no problem with that.

However, this *is* why we *prefer* to avoid having contradictions in premises.   They do not make anything derived from them invalid, but the proofs are quite vacuous.

---

**Remark:**  This is for Classical Logic.  There is a proof system called Relevance Logic which does require that the conclusion of a sub-proof be *relevant* to the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. The premises 1,2 and 3 entail a contradiction: **B & ~B**.

[Ex falso (aka: Principle of explosion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) is a valid rule of inference: we can derive a formula whatever from a contradiction.

Your teacher used the equivalent [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).